# Dynamically change version number of Lambda Layer using a shell executable

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, macos, zsh

I am using a shell script that calls for some custom packages to be zipped and layered on lambda.

After deploying the layer via `aws lambda publish-layer-version` the layer version, obviously, goes up. The next command in my .sh script is something like

`aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name myfunc --layers arn:aws:lambda:<region>:273846758499:layer:<layer_name>:<version>`

Since I am new to scripting in general I am open to any workable solutions but I am looking to iterate the `<version>` to the most recent version available on Lambda. How can this be written in this language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply parse the response from the first command:

For example, I'm using here `jq`, which parses jsons in bash.

`version=$(aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name <your name> --zip-file <zip> --region "us-east-1" | jq -r '.LayerVersionArn')`

Then, you can upload with:
`aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name <name> --layers $version`

Disclosure: I work for Lumigo, a company that provides serverless monitoring.

Comment: Thanks. Homebrew installed jq and used it. Very handy. Also opened my eyes to possibilities of using multiple commands in line with, for example, `| python3 "<code>"` and that, plus this, have taken me further. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `publish-layer-version`, it always creates a `unique ARN` for every `lambda function`.

I was stuck in the same situation when I created the `continuous deployment/delivery pipeline`. When the user pushes to the `main` branch, then the code directly deploys into the `lambda function` and creates or updates the `lambda layer`. But I am confused about how to connect the `lambda function` to the `lambda layers`.

That time, I had to do something like this.

`layer=$(aws lambda list-layers --query "Layers[0].LayerArn")`

`aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name $lambda_function_name --layers $layer`